# Nested Quantifiers, "Unique" or "Exactly One" Example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

### Question

Let `L(x, y)` be the predicate: `"x likes y"`, where the domains are given by: `x is a CS student and y is a kind of food.`

Let `D(x)` be the predicate: `"x is a student in this discrete class"`, where the domain is: `all CS students`.

Express the following statement using those predicates and any required quantifiers. You may use only universal and existential quantifiers.

(a) There is exactly one CS student who likes tofu.

### Response

**My answer**: ∃x∀y(L(x, tofu) ∧ ((y ≠ x) ⟹ ¬L(x, y))

What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Your answer expresses "there is a CS student who likes tofu and likes no food other than himself." In particular, this student has to be tofu.

Comment: @AndreasBlass This has to be one of the funniest replies that I've seen on MSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t$ stand for tofu. Let $CS$ be the set of all CS majors.

Then
\begin{align}
&
&
&\exists! x \in CS \, L(x,t)
&
&\text{Exactly one CS student likes $t$.}
\\[1ex]
&\text{i.e.,} &\quad
&\exists x \in CS \, \bigl[ L(x,t) \wedge \forall y \in CS \, (L(y,t) \to y = x ) \bigr]
&
&\begin{array}
$\text{A CS student $x$ likes $t$, and every} \\ \text{CS student that likes $t$ must be $x$.}\end{array}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one student $x$ that likes tofu such as all students in the CS class that are not $x$ don't like tofu. It's easy to show that $x$ is unique.